# UITextView Text cut off when using setContentInset

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I'm trying to shift the text in my UITextView right by 20 pixels to create a text indent using the code below

```
[textview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0,-20)];
```

But this is cutting off the right hand side of my text as shown in the screenshot. Can any help me stop this happening please

[image]

Comment: Please see this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12357042/312312

Comment: I think that answer is for a TextField rather than a TextView?

Comment: Actually it's not working as it should with the solution I provided as it is not setting correctly the caret in the UITextView. I'm going to remove the solution.

Comment: Another issue is that the width of the text area doesn't expand when rotated horizontally

Comment: I didn't notice the issue with the caret

Comment: I would say that is far more simpler to place the UITextView with a transparent background over an UIImageView that has the notepad image and set the UITextView frame to the right instead...

Comment: The trouble with that is i draw the lines programayically. What was the issue with caret? It seems to work fine for me

Comment: You still can draw them in code. But add them to a separate view below the UITextView. The carret position was incorrect. Text was being added below the actual position of the cursor with the latest solution I did provide to overcome the issue when editing text

Comment: OK i'll look into drawing in subviews. Shame as the solution was so close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to your problem even by subclassing UITextView and blocking setContentSize which seemed to be the problem.

```
[textview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, rightInset)];
```

No matter what is the value of the rightInset the text is always clipped. Something is always redrawing text so that it fits the frame width of the text view. 
But I am wondering why do you need to set the inset? Can't you just set the background of the UITextView object to clear color and position it properly on your background view to get the illusion of indentation?

Answer (score 2):

I think your edge insets are a bit off. Edge insets work towards the middle of the rectangle. For the right inset you should try 20 rather than -20.

```
[textview setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 20)];
```

Comment: Thanks but this just makes the view wider by 40px.